# Unity Firebase "Unable to load options for default app" error

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

When I run the app this error pops up:

> Unable to load options for default app ([D:/Projects/Unity/‏‏PullApp/Assets/StreamingAssets\google-services-desktop.json, D:/Projects/Unity/‏‏PullApp/Assets/StreamingAssets\google-services.json] are missing or malformed)
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   Firebase.Platform.FirebaseLogger:LogMessage(PlatformLogLevel, String) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.4oHf4jn9P6/firebase/app/client/unity/src/Unity/FirebaseLogger.cs:19)
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:LogMessage(LogLevel, String) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.n6hJS53AxW/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/FirebaseApp.cs:90)
>   Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE:FirebaseApp_CreateInternal__SWIG_0()
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateInternal() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.n6hJS53AxW/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/FirebaseApp.cs:976)
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:m__0() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.n6hJS53AxW/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/FirebaseApp.cs:144)
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateAndTrack(CreateDelegate, FirebaseApp) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.n6hJS53AxW/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/FirebaseApp.cs:537)
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:Create() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.n6hJS53AxW/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/FirebaseApp.cs:144)
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:get_DefaultInstance() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.n6hJS53AxW/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/FirebaseApp.cs:116)
>   DBManager:InitializeFirebase() (at Assets/Scripts/DBManager.cs:30)
>   DBManager:b__0_0(Task`1) (at Assets/Scripts/DBManager.cs:17)
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback:PerformWaitCallback()

It already worked perfectly on this project, and I don't know what I did that changed it (I can't use Ctrl+Z cause I've closed the app several times since it happened in trying to fix this..)
I've already tried to delete all the assets related to firebase and re-import them, still the same error occurs.
Also, When I press the error it self, it leds me the this line in my code:

```
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
```

tho it's the default line of firebase it self so..

Please help me. I've tried everything and I'm stuck :/

Answer (score 6):

In my case Special sign in filepath caused this error!

Comment: For me too... "special" characters like áéíóöőúüű, etc. will break things... *sigh* it's almost 2021 and we still live in 1900s... anyways. Thank you for this idea!

Comment: Lol, same here. I never thought that having for example a german or a scandinavian letter in the path would break anything. I mean... And this is a google product :D

Answer (score 4):

google-services json file should be named as "google-services". Other names like "google-services(1)" will give error.

Answer (score 3):

google-services files should be placed into `AsseStreamingAssets` folder and it solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem because the project name and path appeared in Chinese, which caused the initialization failure

Answer (score 0):

It said that 
"[D:/Projects/Unity/‏‏PullApp/Assets/StreamingAssets\google-services-desktop.json, D:/Projects/Unity/‏‏PullApp/Assets/StreamingAssets\google-services.json] are missing or malformed)".

You need to put the google-services.json into your Assets folder.(According to the doc, you can place the Firebase config files anywhere within the Assets folder.)

If you're registering both an iOS and an Android build target of your Unity project, you'll need to download and add the config files for both platforms.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

Answer (score 0):

Well nothing seem to work so I've created a new project from scratch and re-attached it to firebase and now it works perfectly fine.
Still It would be nice to know what happened there...

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this error and found that my editor had created `google-services.json.txt` instead of `google-services.json`.

I recommend opening the files in something like Visual Studio just in case Windows is hiding extensions from you, too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just add the Google-Services JSON file to another folder called "StreamingAssets" inside the Assets folder and the error disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the google-services.json file in `Assests/StreamingAssests`